# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ or showing it does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

> Does the following limit exist?
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

If yes, then I have to find it; if no, then I need to give reason why.

I couldn’t figure out how to prove this formally, can someone please help me out.

Comment: Use the fact that $|\sin (\frac1  x) | \leq 1$. Apply Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774391/if-fx-x-sin-frac-pix-is-continuous-everywhere-then-find-f0/3774513#3774513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Approach**

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \leq |x| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Thus, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta = \varepsilon$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
0 < |x - 0| < \delta \Rightarrow \left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 0\right| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

whence we conclude the given function converges to zero as $x$ approaches zero.

**Second Approach**

The limit exists and converges to zero due to the sandwich theorem.

That is because $x\to 0$ and the $\sin$ function is bounded.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can let $$z=\frac{1}{x}$$ so then the limit becomes $$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{z} \sin z \:,$$ which clearly pulls down to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the limit there exist. Note that the funcion $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a [bounded function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function), with   $$|\sin(x)|\leq 1 \iff -1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$$
Therefore, $$-1\leq \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leq 1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} -x \leq \lim_{x\to 0} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leq \lim_{x\to 0}x$$
$$ 0\leq \lim_{x\to 0} x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leq 0$$
Finally, by the well-know [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) we can conclude that $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0}}$$

Comment: You can considerer, two case if $x\in\mathbb{R}^{-}$ and if $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, in both case you have that if $x\to 0$, so $-x\to 0$.So, in the limit the inequality does not change.

Answer (score 1):

$$-1 \le \sin {x} \le 1$$

$$-|x| \le x \sin \frac{1}{x} \le |x|$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} -|x| \le \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \frac{1}{x} \le \lim_{x \to 0} |x|$$

$$0 \le \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \frac{1}{x} \le 0$$

This means a limit *does* exist and is 0:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \frac{1}{x} = 0$$