# Difference between two methods

Tags: limits, derivatives

$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x}) & x\neq 0 \\
      \ 0 & x=0  
   \end{cases}
\ $

Check Differentiability at $x$=$0$

**My Approach:**

$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}=\lim_{x\to0} x\sin\frac{1}{x}$.

this limit is defined, so indeed the function is differentiable at zero.

**Second Approach**
If i derivate functions directly and calculate $f'(0^+)$ and $f'(0^-)$.

$f'(x)=x^2 \cdot \cos(\frac{1}{x}) \cdot (\frac{-1}{x^2}))+2x\; \cdot \sin (\frac{1}{x})$

So $f'(x)=\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ which lies in  [-1,1] for $x$ approaching to $0$.

Hence Limit does not exist.

So function must be non-differentiable.

Why second method give false result when i directly differentiate.

**For all other question except in question when function is oscillating i get same result by both method**

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774391/if-fx-x-sin-frac-pix-is-continuous-everywhere-then-find-f0/3774513#3774513

Comment: Why the differential geometry tag?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong when you write that “So function must be non-differentiable”. And your own example shows that: $f$ is differentiable at $0$, but $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: that is what i am asking for why by second method i am not getting  correct answer.

Comment: Because your “second method” is not method at all. If the limit $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ exist, then, yes, you can deduce that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and that $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$. But if it doesn't exist, you deduce nothing.